# How to get the Managers active descendants count

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to create a query that display the Employee, Manager, Active, and the active descendants under the manager's hierarchy. Anyone can help me on this?

Results:

```
/* EmployeeId   ManagerId   IsActive    NoofDescendantsActive
    1           -1       0              4                   
    2            1       1              3
    3            1       0              2
    4            2       1              2
    6            2       0              0
    7            3       1              0
    8            3       1              0
    9            4       1              1
    10           9       1              0
    11           9       0              0
```

*/

```
create table Person
(
    EmployeeId int,
    ManagerId int,
    IsActive bit
);

insert into Person(EmployeeId,ManagerId,IsActive) values
(1, -1, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 0),
(4, 2, 1),
(6, 2, 0),
(7, 3, 1),
(8, 3, 1),
(9, 4, 1),
(10, 9, 1),
(11, 9, 0);
```

Comment: Give your expected output

Comment: @cris gomez - How are you calculating active descendants?  Employee ID #1 appears to have 1 active direct descentend, but 6 total active descendants.  Wondering how you get 3?

Comment: @D.L., under the ID# 1 hierarchy, is ID#2(active) and ID#3(not active) base on IsActive field, under ID#2, is ID#4(active) and ID#6(not active), ID#3 has no descendants, Under ID#4 is ID#9(active), Under ID#9 is ID#10(active) and ID#11(not active). Since we are getting the active descendants we only get 3 No of Active Decendants. If you need more info just message here. Thanks

Comment: @D.L. sorry the No Active descendants should be 4.

Comment: @chris gomez - Ahh, got it.  So to be part of the tree every entry in the tree must be active.  (i.e. So 7 and 8 are orphans because 3 is inactive.)

Comment: Yes @D.L. you got it!

Comment: @Utsav, I've already put the Output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43961236/11432) of Giorgos has a flaw. If employee #6 is [made active](http://rextester.com/XZITSE87440), manager #1 should increase by 1 only. However, in his solution, it increased by 2.

```
EmployeeId  NoofDescendantsActive
1           6
2           4
3           2
4           2
9           1
```

Here's a solution that works:

```
with Managers as
(
    select 
        RootManagerId = EmployeeId, IsActive
    from dbo.Person
    where EmployeeId in (select ManagerId from dbo.Person where IsActive = 1)    
),
A as -- Manager with employees
(
    select m.RootManagerId, AnchorManagerId = m.RootManagerId, 
           ManagerId = convert(int, null)
    from Managers m

    union all

    select m.RootManagerId, AnchorManagerId = d.EmployeeId, 
           d.ManagerId
    from A m
    -- collect descendants
    join dbo.Person d on m.AnchorManagerId = d.ManagerId and d.IsActive = 1
),
Solution as
(
    select RootManagerId, count(*) as Descendants
    from A
    where ManagerId is not null
    group by RootManagerId
)
-- select * from A order by RootManagerId; -- Uncomment to see how things works
select * from Solution;
```

[Result](http://rextester.com/XMD13935):

```
RootManagerId   Descendants
1               4
2               3
3               2
4               2
9               1
```

Here's the [result](http://rextester.com/VPNEZ12637) if employee #6 is made active:

```
RootManagerId   Descendants
1               5
2               4
3               2
4               2
9               1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the desired result using the following *recursive CTE*:

```
;WITH Descendants_CTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: Get leaf nodes first
    SELECT p1.EmployeeId, p1.ManagerId, p1.IsActive, 0 AS level
    FROM Person AS p1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM Person AS p2
                      WHERE p2.ManagerId = p1.EmployeeId)

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member: Get nodes of next level, keep track of
    -- the number of active nodes so far
    SELECT p.EmployeeId, p.ManagerId, p.IsActive, level = level + 1
    FROM Person AS p
    INNER JOIN Descendants_CTE AS d ON p.EmployeeId = d.ManagerId
    WHERE d.IsActive = 1        
)
SELECT EmployeeId, SUM(level) AS NoofDescendantsActive
FROM Descendants_CTE
WHERE level > 0
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

The recursion traverses the tree 'bottom-up', adding up the number of 'active' nodes met so far. If a non-active node is met traversal is terminated. Using a `GROUP BY` we can get the total number of active nodes beneath each non-leaf node. If you want to get the additional fields as well, then you have to `JOIN` the above query to the original table.

**Hint:** To better understand how the algorithm of the query actually works you can construct a graph of the tree on a piece of paper. Highlight each active node using a colored marker.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/NDKCC30189)

Comment: Thanks Giorgos Betsos. :)

Comment: @crisgomez Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.